# compact(): Argument #2 must be string or array of strings, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
$maincategory = Category::all(['id', 'category']);
$maintable = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
$subcategory = Subcategory::all(['id', 'subcategory']);
$subtable = Subcategory::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
return view('admin.news.create', compact('maincategory', $maincategory, 'maintable','subcategory',$subcategory,'subtable'));
```

am getting error on this

```
return view('admin.news.create', compact('maincategory', $maincategory, 'maintable','subcategory',$subcategory,'subtable'));
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use query result collection in `compact`.

```
return view('admin.news.create', compact('maincategory','subcategory'));
```

Here `compact('maincategory', ...)` will send `$maincategory`  and `subcategory` will send `$subcategory` to the view `admin.news.create`.

You can also use **with()** like this

```
return view('admin.news.create')->with('maincategory',$maincategory)->with('subcategory',$subcategory)
```

You can access it like this in your view blade

```
foreach($maincategory as $category)
{
 // Code
}

foreach($subcategory as $s_category)
{
 // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says: *compact: must be string or string of Array*, so, if your `variables` are more than one, pass it this way:

```
return view('admin.news.create', compact(
  ['maincategory', 
   'maintable',
   'subcategory',
   'subtable'
  ]
);
```

But if your `variable` is just one, then thats when you use `string`

```
return view('admin.news.create', compact('maincategory'));
```